# Measuring loading time of Excel

Tags: java, excel

I am searching for a solution for over one week. Maybe you have a good solution to this problem:

I want to measure the time I need to open an Excel file with Excel. My first solution is that I start the measurement with this line of code:

```
ProcessBuilder command = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                        <EXCEL_PATH>,
                        <FILE-LOCATION>);
                command.start();
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And i check the RAM-Usage via the process explorer. If excel finish loading the ram usage is still the same and I stop the measurement. As you see this is very fuzzy and not a good solution.

As second solution I open a SocketServer in JAVA and wait until Excel will call the Workbook_Open()- Method after finishing loading the file. Within this method I send a socket connection to the java server (I give the host and port as parameter to excel) and measure this time.

This is very efficient BUT in my company it is not allowed to auto run scripts if they don’t stored in a trusted zone. I cannot change the policy’s so it is not a solution. Does anyone have an idea how to measure the loading time of an Excel-File in Excel? It could not be that their is no solution to track the loading time in Excel?

Comment: Is it a specific excel file, or could the file change?

Comment: use a progress bar and time that?

Comment: @ Miss Palmer: the file could change

Comment: @Huang Chen: how could a progress bar measure if excle is loading or not?

Comment: I don't know how you managed to spell my first name AND my last name wrong but I digress, I'll provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer:

You can use DDE for attempting to connect (initiate a conversation) to the desired file repeatedly, and measure the time that passes until you succeed.

Please notice it will be far from a precise measuring, and should be used mainly for estimation.

Have a look at [this project](https://github.com/Lightstreamer/Lightstreamer-example-StockList-client-dde) which is based on [this one](http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/en/examples/), for an example of using DDE together with Java and MS Excel.


 
**Details:**

You can't connect to an Excel file by DDE before its loading has completed inside Excel program, and that can serve the purpose.
Right after starting Excel, you can attempt to connect to the file by DDE (repeatedly or with 100ms delay for avoiding CPU load) until you succeed, and calculate the time after success.

Pseudo code:

```
ts = now(); 
d = DDE("file.xlsx"); 
while (d.error) { 
    d = DDE("file.xlsx"); 
} 
load_time = now() - ts;
```

---

<strike>*Old version of answer:* If you already use the workbook's VBA, I think there's a simple solution.</strike>

You can write the current time to some new temporary local file, right before opening the file, and then write the current time (`Now`) from within the `Workbook_Open` subroutine, to the same temporary file, at the second line.

Then you will be able to track the file until it has 2 lines with an ongoing interval, and calculate the difference between the timestamps.

Comment: The Problem is: "in my company it is not allowed to auto run scripts"

Comment: Sorry, thought you were referring the socket connection to the java server when you mentioned "trusted zone", not the script itself.
I'm afraid there's no a possible way to track a full loading of an app outside of it, without any involvement of the app itself.

Comment: @MrT opening the excel file within java is a must?

Comment: Right. But not to start the MS Excel Programm and getting Information out of the MS Excel Programm. I dont Need to read the Excel-File-Data within Java.

Comment: @MrT: If the OS is Windows, perhaps you can use DDE.
Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Lightstreamer/Lightstreamer-example-StockList-client-dde) proect which is based on [this one](http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/en/examples/).

You can attempt to connect (initiate a conversation) to the desired file repeatedly, and measure the time once you succeed.

Tell me if you can take off from there and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I thought about DDE, too. But i dont think that it is possible to track the "starting & loading"-time of Excel for a File with DDE. Please correct me if i wrong but i can connect to an existing loaded file within the excel process and can't connect to the excel process if excel is still startig up or?

Comment: You are right, and that's exactly what I meant. You can't connect to a file by DDE before it has loaded, and that can serve the purpose. Have another look at my comment please. I meant that right after starting Excel, you can attempt to connect to the file by DDE (repeatedly or with 100ms delay for avoiding CPU load) until you succeed, and calculate the time after success. Pseudo code: `ts = now(); d = DDE("file.xlsx"); while (d.error) {  d = DDE("file.xlsx"); } load_time = now() - ts;`. It will not provide a 100% of precision, but it should do the work for estimated load time.

Comment: not at the moment - have to find some time for this old work task. maybe during christmas break :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i try it. It will be not as exactly as i wish too, but it still works better than my solution! So noone else has seems to find a solution for this ( i thought easy) problem. i accept this :). Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Updated the answer accordingly, thanks for accepting :)